# I am getting error when using Attributes in Rcpp and have RcppArmadillo code

Tags: r, rcpp, armadillo

I am trying to create a package with RcppArmadillo.  The code uses the new attributes methodology of Rcpp.  The sourceCpp works fine and compiles the code, but when I build a package I get errors when I use RcppArmadillo code.  Without the RcppArmadillo code and using regulare C++, I do not get these errors.
The C++ code (it is essentially the fastLm sample code) is:

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]


#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

using namespace Rcpp;


// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::export]]
List fastLm(NumericVector yr, NumericMatrix Xr) {
      int n = Xr.nrow(), k = Xr.ncol();
  arma::mat X(Xr.begin(), n, k, false);
  arma::colvec y(yr.begin(), yr.size(), false);
  arma::colvec coef = arma::solve(X, y);
  arma::colvec resid = y - X*coef;
  double sig2 = arma::as_scalar(arma::trans(resid)*resid/(n-k));
  arma::colvec stderrest = arma::sqrt(
  sig2 * arma::diagvec( arma::inv(arma::trans(X)*X)) );
  return List::create(Named("coefficients") = coef,
  Named("stderr") = stderrest);
}
```

Here is the compilation error, after I execute "R

```
> Rcpp::compileAttributes()

* Updated src/RcppExports.cpp

==> Rcmd.exe INSTALL --no-multiarch NewPackage

* installing to library 'C:/Users/Howard/Documents/R/win-library/2.15'
* installing *source* package 'NewPackage' ...
** libs
g++ -m64 -I"C:/R/R-2-15-2/include" -DNDEBUG    -I"C:/Users/Howard/Documents/R/win-library/2.15/Rcpp/include" -I"C:/Users/Howard/Documents/R/win-library/2.15/RcppArmadillo/include" -I"d:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
g++ -m64 -I"C:/R/R-2-15-2/include" -DNDEBUG    -I"C:/Users/Howard/Documents/R/win-library/2.15/Rcpp/include" -I"C:/Users/Howard/Documents/R/win-library/2.15/RcppArmadillo/include" -I"d:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c test_arma3.cpp -o test_arma3.o
g++ -m64 -shared -s -static-libgcc -o NewPackage.dll tmp.def RcppExports.o test_arma3.o C:/Users/Howard/Documents/R/win-library/2.15/Rcpp/lib/x64/libRcpp.a -Ld:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/lib/x64 -Ld:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/lib -LC:/R/R-2-15-2/bin/x64 -lR
test_arma3.o:test_arma3.cpp:(.text+0xae4): undefined reference to `dgemm_'
test_arma3.o:test_arma3.cpp:(.text+0x19db): undefined reference to `dgemm_'
test_arma3.o:test_arma3.cpp:(.text+0x1b0c): undefined reference to `dgemv_'
test_arma3.o:test_arma3.cpp:(.text$_ZN4arma6auxlib8solve_odIdNS_3MatIdEEEEbRNS2_IT_EES6_RKNS_4BaseIS4_T0_EE[_ZN4arma6auxlib8solve_odIdNS_3MatIdEEEEbRNS2_IT_EES6_RKNS_4BaseIS4_T0_EE]+0x702): undefined reference to `dgels_'
test_arma3.o:test_arma3.cpp:(.text$_ZN4arma6auxlib8solve_udIdNS_3MatIdEEEEbRNS2_IT_EES6_RKNS_4BaseIS4_T0_EE[_ZN4arma6auxlib8solve_udIdNS_3MatIdEEEEbRNS2_IT_EES6_RKNS_4BaseIS4_T0_EE]+0x51c): undefined reference to `dgels_'
test_arma3.o:test_arma3.cpp:(.text$_ZN4arma6auxlib10det_lapackIdEET_RKNS_3MatIS2_EEb[_ZN4arma6auxlib10det_lapackIdEET_RKNS_3MatIS2_EEb]+0x14b): undefined reference to `dgetrf_'
test_arma3.o:test_arma3.cpp:(.text$_ZN4arma6auxlib5solveIdNS_3MatIdEEEEbRNS2_IT_EES6_RKNS_4BaseIS4_T0_EEb[_ZN4arma6auxlib5solveIdNS_3MatIdEEEEbRNS2_IT_EES6_RKNS_4BaseIS4_T0_EEb]+0x375): undefined reference to `dgesv_'
test_arma3.o:test_arma3.cpp:(.text$_ZN4arma4gemvILb1ELb0ELb0EE15apply_blas_typeIdEEvPT_RKNS_3MatIS3_EEPKS3_S3_S3_[_ZN4arma4gemvILb1ELb0ELb0EE15apply_blas_typeIdEEvPT_RKNS_3MatIS3_EEPKS3_S3_S3_]+0x17d): undefined reference to `dgemv_'
test_arma3.o:test_arma3.cpp:(.text$_ZN4arma27glue_times_redirect2_helperILb1EE5applyINS_2OpINS_3MatIdEENS_9op_htransEEES5_EEvRNS4_INT_9elem_typeEEERKNS_4GlueIS8_T0_NS_10glue_timesEEE[_ZN4arma27glue_times_redirect2_helperILb1EE5applyINS_2OpINS_3MatIdEENS_9op_htransEEES5_EEvRNS4_INT_9elem_typeEEERKNS_4GlueIS8_T0_NS_10glue_timesEEE]+0x37a): undefined reference to `dgemm_'
test_arma3.o:test_arma3.cpp:(.text$_ZN4arma10op_diagvec5applyINS_2OpINS_4GlueINS2_INS_3MatIdEENS_9op_htransEEES5_NS_10glue_timesEEENS_6op_invEEEEEvRNS4_INT_9elem_typeEEERKNS2_ISC_S0_EE[_ZN4arma10op_diagvec5applyINS_2OpINS_4GlueINS2_INS_3MatIdEENS_9op_htransEEES5_NS_10glue_timesEEENS_6op_invEEEEEvRNS4_INT_9elem_typeEEERKNS2_ISC_S0_EE]+0x2c1): undefined reference to `dgetrf_'
test_arma3.o:test_arma3.cpp:(.text$_ZN4arma10op_diagvec5applyINS_2OpINS_4GlueINS2_INS_3MatIdEENS_9op_htransEEES5_NS_10glue_timesEEENS_6op_invEEEEEvRNS4_INT_9elem_typeEEERKNS2_ISC_S0_EE[_ZN4arma10op_diagvec5applyINS_2OpINS_4GlueINS2_INS_3MatIdEENS_9op_htransEEES5_NS_10glue_timesEEENS_6op_invEEEEEvRNS4_INT_9elem_typeEEERKNS2_ISC_S0_EE]+0x322): undefined reference to `dgetri_'
test_arma3.o:test_arma3.cpp:(.text$_ZN4arma10op_diagvec5applyINS_2OpINS_4GlueINS2_INS_3MatIdEENS_9op_htransEEES5_NS_10glue_timesEEENS_6op_invEEEEEvRNS4_INT_9elem_typeEEERKNS2_ISC_S0_EE[_ZN4arma10op_diagvec5applyINS_2OpINS_4GlueINS2_INS_3MatIdEENS_9op_htransEEES5_NS_10glue_timesEEENS_6op_invEEEEEvRNS4_INT_9elem_typeEEERKNS2_ISC_S0_EE]+0x398): undefined reference to `dgetri_'
test_arma3.o:test_arma3.cpp:(.text$_ZN4arma10op_diagvec5applyINS_2OpINS_4GlueINS2_INS_3MatIdEENS_9op_htransEEES5_NS_10glue_timesEEENS_6op_invEEEEEvRNS4_INT_9elem_typeEEERKNS2_ISC_S0_EE[_ZN4arma10op_diagvec5applyINS_2OpINS_4GlueINS2_INS_3MatIdEENS_9op_htransEEES5_NS_10glue_timesEEENS_6op_invEEEEEvRNS4_INT_9elem_typeEEERKNS2_ISC_S0_EE]+0x775): undefined reference to `dgetrf_'
test_arma3.o:test_arma3.cpp:(.text$_ZN4arma10op_diagvec5applyINS_2OpINS_4GlueINS2_INS_3MatIdEENS_9op_htransEEES5_NS_10glue_timesEEENS_6op_invEEEEEvRNS4_INT_9elem_typeEEERKNS2_ISC_S0_EE[_ZN4arma10op_diagvec5applyINS_2OpINS_4GlueINS2_INS_3MatIdEENS_9op_htransEEES5_NS_10glue_timesEEENS_6op_invEEEEEvRNS4_INT_9elem_typeEEERKNS2_ISC_S0_EE]+0x7d6): undefined reference to `dgetri_'
test_arma3.o:test_arma3.cpp:(.text$_ZN4arma10op_diagvec5applyINS_2OpINS_4GlueINS2_INS_3MatIdEENS_9op_htransEEES5_NS_10glue_timesEEENS_6op_invEEEEEvRNS4_INT_9elem_typeEEERKNS2_ISC_S0_EE[_ZN4arma10op_diagvec5applyINS_2OpINS_4GlueINS2_INS_3MatIdEENS_9op_htransEEES5_NS_10glue_timesEEENS_6op_invEEEEEvRNS4_INT_9elem_typeEEERKNS2_ISC_S0_EE]+0x892): undefined reference to `dgetri_'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'NewPackage'
* removing 'C:/Users/Howard/Documents/R/win-library/2.15/NewPackage'
* restoring previous 'C:/Users/Howard/Documents/R/win-library/2.15/NewPackage'

Exited with status 1.
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you cross-posted this to the `rcpp-devel` list, and per [this thread](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.r.rcpp/4457) it should now be taken care of.

Comment: Maybe you could edit to add that what is said there, that it is needed to fix it is adding Makevars and Makevars.win files with `PKG_LIBS=$(LAPACK_LIBS) $(BLAS_LIBS) $(FLIBS)` inside (and that `RcppArmadillo.package.skeleton()` takes care of it)? I had similar issue and it took me half an hour to find the solution on the web.

Comment: Just use `RcppArmadillo.package.skeleton()` ?  See the Rcpp FAQ?

Comment: Well, yes, you are perfectly right, but for example, in my case I switched old Rcpp code entirely to RcppArmadillo and was not building package from the scratch, so I didn't thought of using `RcppArmadillo.package.skeleton()`, just changed the inludes, LinkingTo etc. and the reason why it was not compiling was not obvious to find and to Google for.

Comment: I hear you. That is actually surprisingly tricky, but the place for documenting that too ... is in the package! And the easiest is by comparing to a working package -- hence the suggestion of `RcppArmadillo.package.skeleton()`.  But by all means propose a pull request if you have something.  Random places on these Intertubes are just that.  You may search here, the next person may not.